# Convegence in Probability but not almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Let $ {a_n}  $ be a sequence of numbers in $ (0,1) $ such that $ a_n\to0  $, but $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_n=\infty$. Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be independent random variables with $$P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=-1)=\frac{a_n}{2}\  \qquad \text{and} \qquad  P(X_n=0)=1-a_n $$ for all $n\ge1$. Define $Y_1=X_1$ and for all $n \ge 2$, 
 $$Y_n =
\begin{cases}
X_n,  & \text{if } Y_{n-1} =0 \\[0.2cm]
nY_{n-1}|X_n|, & \text{if } Y_{n-1} \neq 0
\end{cases}$$

Show that $Y_n$ converges in probability but not almost surely.

I have already shown $Y_n\to0$ in probability. I need help with the second part.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the [second Borel–Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) to the event $E_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \{X_n=0\}$, since $\mathbb{P}\{Y_n=0\} = \mathbb{P}\{X_n=0\}$?

Comment: @ClementC. OP is trying to show that $Y_n$ does *not* converge a.s., which requires the first Borel-Cantelli lemma. Unfortunately, this is not satisfied for $\{Y_n=0\}$ so other methods are needed.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: By $Y_{(n-1)}$ you mean $Y_{n-1}$ or something else?

Comment: Edited. I meant $Y_{n-1}$ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events $\{Y_n=0\}$ are independent, thus $P(Y_n=0)=1-a_n \implies \sum P(Y_n=0)=\sum(1-a_n) = \infty - \infty$ but this is indeterminate, and thus we cannot apply the second lemma diretly to the event of interest.

However, since the set of events $\{\{Y_n=0\},\{Y_n \neq 0\}\}$ partition the sample space, we can conclude that $\{Y_n\neq 0\}$ are also independent. Thus, we can apply the second lemma to this series to get:

$$ \sum P(Y_n \neq 0) = \sum a_n = \infty \implies P(\lim \sup Y_n \neq 0) = 1 \implies P(\lim \sup Y_n=0)=0 \;\;\;\square$$